# How to spy on a function with Jest

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme, ts-jest

I am writing this question after spending enough time on related questions and none of the solutions work. Any help is greatly appreciated and would mean a lot.

I have a function like this: This is in the path utility/apiUtility

```
export const getService = (params: any) => {
    return managedAxios.get(params.url, { headers: (params.headers) })
}
```

I have another function which makes a call to the above function in the dataServices file:

```
export const fetchData = async (url: string) => {
    try {
        const response = await getService({
            url: `some_valid_url`,
            headers: { valid_headers }
        })
        return response.data
    } catch (error) {
        //catch implementation here
    }
    return undefined
}
```

And finally here is my test:

```
import * as services from "./dataServices"
import * as utils from "utility/apiUtility"
     it("should fetch feature flag details", async () => {
            const spy = jest.spyOn(utils,'getService').mockImplementation( () => ({ getService: jest.fn(() => {
                console.log("inside get")
                Promise.resolve(true)
            }) }))
            services.fetchData("url")
            expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
        })
```

I have those 2 imports in my test file. And when I run the test, I'm getting the error as

```
Cannot spy the getService property because it is not a function; undefined given instead
```

Any help will mean a lot. Thanks in advance